# Custom CSS: Using All-In-One Cufon in the Header

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, cufon

I have All-In-One Cufon installed on [my website](http://www.shaunhillphotography.co.uk). I like the way it is working at the moment, using `Cufon.replace('h1')('h2')('h3')("h4")("h5")("h6")("pre")("abbr");`. However, I want the header links to appear using Cufon too. I had it set to ("a") too, but this changed all the links on the website, which now look wrong.

Does anyone have a way of getting the header links to display using Cufon, without using the ("a") tag (which otherwise renders all links in all sizes using the same process)?

Comment: I found the solution finally!

    Cufon.replace('h1')('h2')('h3')("h4")("h5")("h6")("pre")("abbr")(".menu");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Cufon.replace('h1')('h2')('h3')("h4")("h5")("h6")("pre")("abbr");` to the following should work:

```
 Cufon.replace('h1')('h2')('h3')("h4")("h5")("h6")("pre")("abbr")('h1 a')('h2 a')('h3 a')('h4 a')('h5 a')('h6 a');
```

or alternately:

```
Cufon.replace('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, abbr, pre, h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a');
```

also should work.

The selector `a` will select all anchor elements, whereas the selector `h1 a` will select all anchor elements contained within an h1 element. Google CSS selectors and specificity for more info.